# Apache 2.2.19 compilation error

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris-10

Facing below error, while compiling apache 2.2.19 in solaris 10 box.

Pleases help me to troubleshoot the issue.

```
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to ab
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `ab'
```

Comment: Please review the answers to the questions you have already asked and if applicable mark the one that was most useful as accepted. This will help the community know that the questions have useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot this by looking at the rest of the output that your compilation produces. Somewhere there will be more detailed messages on what symbols have not been referenced and where.